# sorting mutidimension array using array_multisort() in php

Tags: php

I have a array structure as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 97
            [1] => 155
            [2] => 160
            [3] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 97
            [1] => 155
            [2] => 161
            [3] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 97
            [1] => 155
            [2] => 572
            [3] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 4
            [3] => Responds when talked to, for example, moves arms and legs, changes facial expression, moves body and makes mouth movements.
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 4
            [3] => Recognises and is most responsive to main carer's voice: face brightens, activity increases when familiar carer appears.
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 97
            [1] => 155
            [2] => 156
            [3] => Makes own sounds in response when talked to by familiar adults.
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 97
            [1] => 155
            [2] => 156
            [3] => Practises and gradually develops speech sounds (babbling) to communicate with adults; says sounds like 'baba, nono, gogo'.
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 356
            [1] => 405
            [2] => 406
            [3] => Gets to know and enjoy daily routines, such as getting-up time, mealtimes, nappy time, and bedtime.
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 356
            [1] => 405
            [2] => 407
            [3] => Attempts, sometimes successfully, to fit shapes into spaces on inset boards or jigsaw puzzles.
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 356
            [1] => 405
            [2] => 407
            [3] => Uses blocks to create their own simple structures and arrangements.
        )

)
```

I use

```
<?php
foreach( $arr as $key => $value ) {
        $a[$key] = $value[3];
        $b[$key] = $value[2];
        $c[$key] = $value[1];
        $d[$key] = $value[0];
    }
    array_multisort($a, SORT_ASC, $b , SORT_ASC, $c, SORT_DESC, $d, SORT_ASC,  $a);
?>
```

And the result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 4
            [3] => Recognises and is most responsive to main carer's voice: face brightens, activity increases when familiar carer appears.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 4
            [3] => Responds when talked to, for example, moves arms and legs, changes facial expression, moves body and makes mouth movements.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 97
            [1] => 155
            [2] => 156
            [3] => Makes own sounds in response when talked to by familiar adults.
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 97
            [1] => 155
            [2] => 156
            [3] => Practises and gradually develops speech sounds (babbling) to communicate with adults; says sounds like 'baba, nono, gogo'.
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 97
            [1] => 155
            [2] => 160
            [3] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 97
            [1] => 155
            [2] => 161
            [3] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 356
            [1] => 405
            [2] => 406
            [3] => Gets to know and enjoy daily routines, such as getting-up time, mealtimes, nappy time, and bedtime.
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 356
            [1] => 405
            [2] => 407
            [3] => Attempts, sometimes successfully, to fit shapes into spaces on inset boards or jigsaw puzzles.
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 356
            [1] => 405
            [2] => 407
            [3] => Uses blocks to create their own simple structures and arrangements.
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 97
            [1] => 155
            [2] => 572
            [3] => 
        )

)
```

In result, why the 97 value in array is not sort. (I think the array index[2] is sorted by ASC )

Answer (score 1):

You do know the order? It's 0-9 and then A-Z. So the array index[3] is sorted by ASC. Try DESC and look what the result is. index[3][3] is at the top of index[3].

Comment: by default `array_multisort` doesn't change the type of the values - means numbers get sorted by value and not alphabetically - and numbers before strings -afaik. You can use sort flags to change that behavior.